# Convert total seconds to ISO 8601 duration string with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wanted to check if `momentjs` is able to convert a given number of seconds to a ISO 8601 formatted duration string.

E.g. 1000 seconds will lead to `PT16M40S`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-duration

Comment: using a library to replace one line of code is kind of crazy.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `toISOString` on the duration:

```
moment.duration(1000, 'seconds').toISOString() //"PT16M40S"
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy It seems that indeed the official docs do lack this method, but it seems to be available since moment.js 2.9.0 [See the implementation here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/497f918515ae6ab900f008f19523b1e4ae5e2450/src/lib/duration/iso-string.js)